# Ayuda con un menú dinámico en wxpython

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

Quisiera consultarles un problema que estoy teniendo con un menú dinámico en wxpython.
Estoy usando wxpython 4.0.3 y Python 3.7.
Bien mi problema es que me gustaría obtener cuando elijo un item del menú que rango es por ejemplo:
[“España”, “Italia”, “Portugal”]
Bien si elijo España me gustaría que me devolviese 0 y así sucesivamente.
Es un popup dinámico ya que la información varia al ser obtenida de internet.
Pongo un ejemplo de lo que tengo echo:

```
def menu_accion(self):
    lista1a = ["España", "Italia", "Portugal"]
    lista1b = ["100", "200", "300"]
    lista2a = ["Gato", "Perro", "Caballo"]
    lista2b = ["100", "200", "300"]
    self.Menu_Principal = wx.Menu()
    self.Sub_1 = wx.Menu()
    for i in range(0, len(lista1b)):
        item =  "item_" + str(i)
        Menu_ID = i
        nombre_item = lista1a[i]
        numero_item = lista1b[i]
        disparador = self.prueba1

        Menu_ID = self.Sub_1.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "{} {}".format(nombre_item, numero_item))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, disparador, id=Menu_ID.GetId())

    self.Menu_Principal.AppendSubMenu(self.Sub_1, "Paises")
    self.Sub_2 = wx.Menu()
    for z in range(0, len(lista2b)):
        Menu_IDz = z
        nombre_itemz = lista2a[z]
        numero_itemz = lista2b[z]
        disparadorz = self.prueba2

        Menu_IDz = self.Sub_2.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "{} {}".format(nombre_itemz, numero_itemz))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, disparadorz, id=Menu_IDz.GetId())

    self.Menu_Principal.AppendSubMenu(self.Sub_2, "Animales")


def mostrar_menu_accion(self,event):
    position = self.Panel.GetPosition()
    self.PopupMenu(self.Menu_Principal,position)
    pass

def prueba1(self, event):
    id_selected = event.GetId()
    print(id_selected)
    print("Pulsado submenú de Paises")
def prueba2(self, event):
    id_selected = event.GetId()
    print(id_selected)
    print("Pulsado submenú de Animales")
```

Bien cuando elijo España por ejemplo me devuelve esto:
-31998
Pulsado submenú de Países
Bien haciendo pruebas y por ejemplo cambiando wx.ID_ANY por Menu_ID me da correctamente que al elegir España es 0 pero se va al def prueba2 indiferentemente si elegí en el menú países o animales.
La verdad e estado buscando mucho y ya no se si de tanto me e liado y no se por donde continuar.
Se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo he entendido, quieres obtener la posición del item seleccionado en el menú. Que yo sepa la clase `wx.Menu` no ofrece ningún método que permita ésto, lo que yo hago es valerme del evento para obtener una referencia del menu y del item, luego uso `wx.Menu.GetMenuItems` que retorna una lista y busco el índice del item en ella con el método `index`:

```
import wx  



class Test(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title)
        self._init_ui()

    def _init_ui(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        wx.StaticText(
            self.panel, -1,
            "Click derecho para mostrar menú", (25, 25)
            )

        self.menu_accion()
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.mostrar_menu_accion)
        self.SetSize((350, 250))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def menu_accion(self):
        lista1a = ["España", "Italia", "Portugal"]
        lista1b = ["100", "200", "300"]
        lista2a = ["Gato", "Perro", "Caballo"]
        lista2b = ["100", "200", "300"]
        self.menu_principal = wx.Menu()
        self.sub_1 = wx.Menu()
        for nombre_item, numero_item in zip(lista1a, lista1b):
            menu_item = self.sub_1.Append(
                wx.ID_ANY, f"{nombre_item} {numero_item}"
                )
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.prueba1, id=menu_item.GetId())
        self.menu_principal.AppendSubMenu(self.sub_1, "Paises")

        self.sub_2 = wx.Menu()
        for nombre_item, numero_item in zip(lista2a, lista2b):
            menu_item = self.sub_2.Append(
                wx.ID_ANY, f"{nombre_item} {numero_item}"
                )
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.prueba2, id=menu_item.GetId())
        self.menu_principal.AppendSubMenu(self.sub_2, "Animales")

    def mostrar_menu_accion(self, event):
        pos = event.GetPosition()
        pos = self.panel.ScreenToClient(pos)
        self.PopupMenu(self.menu_principal, pos)

    def prueba1(self, event):
        menu = event.EventObject
        item = menu.FindItemById(event.GetId())
        indice = menu.GetMenuItems().index(item)
        item_label = item.GetItemLabel()
        print("Pulsado submenú de Paises")
        print(f"Item: {item_label}")
        print(f"Indice: {indice}")

    def prueba2(self, event):
        menu = event.EventObject
        item = menu.FindItemById(event.GetId())
        indice = menu.GetMenuItems().index(item)
        item_label = item.GetItemLabel()
        print("Pulsado submenú de Animales")
        print(f"Item: {item_label}")
        print(f"Indice: {indice}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Test(None, 'Menú test')
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si por alguna razón lo anterior no funciona (ver comentarios), siempre existe la posibilidad de usar un wrapper y pasar a la callback directamente el índice como argumento. Para ello podemos usar expresiones lambda con argumentos por defecto, una funcion/método normales o la mejor opción y más simple, `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

import wx  



class Test(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title)
        self._init_ui()

    def _init_ui(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        wx.StaticText(
            self.panel, -1,
            "Click derecho para mostrar menú", (25, 25)
            )

        self.menu_accion()
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.mostrar_menu_accion)
        self.SetSize((350, 250))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def menu_accion(self):
        lista1a = ["España", "Italia", "Portugal"]
        lista1b = ["100", "200", "300"]
        lista2a = ["Gato", "Perro", "Caballo"]
        lista2b = ["100", "200", "300"]
        self.menu_principal = wx.Menu()
        self.sub_1 = wx.Menu()
        for ix, (nombre_item, numero_item) in enumerate(zip(lista1a, lista1b)):
            menu_item = self.sub_1.Append(
                wx.ID_ANY, f"{nombre_item} {numero_item}"
                )
            self.Bind(
                wx.EVT_MENU,
                partial(self.prueba1, indice=ix),
                id=menu_item.GetId()
                )
        self.menu_principal.AppendSubMenu(self.sub_1, "Paises")

        self.sub_2 = wx.Menu()
        for ix, (nombre_item, numero_item) in enumerate(zip(lista2a, lista2b)):
            menu_item = self.sub_2.Append(
                wx.ID_ANY, f"{nombre_item} {numero_item}"
                )
            self.Bind(
                wx.EVT_MENU,
                partial(self.prueba2, indice=ix),
                id=menu_item.GetId()
                )
        self.menu_principal.AppendSubMenu(self.sub_2, "Animales")

    def mostrar_menu_accion(self, event):
        pos = event.GetPosition()
        pos = self.panel.ScreenToClient(pos)
        self.PopupMenu(self.menu_principal, pos)

    def prueba1(self, event, indice=None):
        menu = event.EventObject
        item = menu.FindItemById(event.GetId())
        item_label = item.GetItemLabel()
        print("Pulsado submenú de Paises")
        print(f"Item: {item_label}")
        print(f"Indice: {indice}")

    def prueba2(self, event, indice=None):
        menu = event.EventObject
        item = menu.FindItemById(event.GetId())
        item_label = item.GetItemLabel()
        print("Pulsado submenú de Animales")
        print(f"Item: {item_label}")
        print(f"Indice: {indice}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Test(None, 'Menú test')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Al contrario que el primer método, éste no depende para nada de la implementación de las clases implicadas o el evento en si, es una forma universal en Python de pasar argumentos a callbacks cuando el método de enlace no provee de medios para ello. La contrapartida es que es estático, si insertamos items en medio de los que hay, eliminamos o reordenamos, se seguirá pasando el índice inicial, tendremos que hacer un reenlace completo de nuevo si queremos actualizar los índices a mostrar.

Comment: Buenas @FJSevilla, su código es justo lo que necesito pero me devuelve el siguiente error:
    indice = menu.GetMenuItems().index(item)
ValueError: sequence.index(x): x not in sequence


Bien quite el .index(item) y realice un type y me dio:
<class 'wx._core.MenuItemList'>
-31998
Ese resultado me lo daba en mi código por lo que no se si ira por ay los tiros.

Bien por lo que entendí wx.ID_ANY asigna un valor interno y creo que es ese. Entonces con .index la busqueda se hace imposible.

Disculpe soy autodidacta y estoy empezando. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No, la id no tiene nada que ver con index ni con lo que retorna `GetMenuItems`. Dicho método retorna las instancias de sus items, no sus ids.  ¿Podrías mostrar lo que te imprime `print(menu.FindItemById(event.GetId()))` y `print(menu.GetMenuItems())`?

Comment: Buenas me devuelve lo siguiente:

<wx._core.MenuItem object at 0x0000025CDDA40EE8>
MenuItemList: [<wx._core.MenuItem object at 0x0000025CDDA480D8>, <wx._core.MenuItem object at 0x0000025CDDA48168>]

Comment: Hola Héctor. ¡Pero que....! Efectivamente el item no está, eso justifica que list.index falle, es más solo hay dos items en la lista (y se supone que en el menú...) y debería haber 3... ¿Ese resultado te lo da mi código tal como ésta o has modificado algo?

Comment: No es su código original. Igualmente probé adaptarlo en mi código y pasa exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: No busque más. Necesito usar wxpython 4.0.3 por temas de accesibilidad con mi lector de pantalla. Ya que en sus ultimas versiones en 32 bits solo han roto algo y se han cargado la parte de la accesibilidad.

Pues bien en la versión de 64 que es la que funciona bien, acabo de actualizarla a la ultima versión 4.1.0 y funciona perfectamente su código.

Comment: Curioso, llevo tiempo sin usar versiones de 32bits, pero se que en 64bits al menos de la 4.0.7 para arriba no hay problema con éste código. PArece como si el item selecionado no se retornara en la lista de items... Si tienes que usar una versión en la que ésto no funcione, hay otra posibilidad que es usar un wrapper mediante functools.partial y pasar el índice a la callback como argumento directamente. Si no quietas o reordenas items después del for en el que los creas no tendrás  problemas y funciona seguro. Si es así, puedo agregar un ejemplo si lo deseas. Un saludo.

Comment: Estoy probando también wxpython 4.1.0 en 32 bits y ya solucionaron los problemas de accesibilidad que habían. Por lo que su código es totalmente valido para lo que necesitaba suponiendo que ya no me regresare a una versión anterior.

Pero le estaría muy agradecido por si acaso si pudiese poner ese ejemplo.

De nuevo mil gracias.

Comment: @Héctor he agregado al final de la respuesta la opción de implementación mediante wrappers. No puedo probar el código ahora mismo, pero creo que todo está bien. Si tiene alguna duda comente sin dudar. Un saludo.